# Are there two morphisms f and g between complexes which induce the same morphisms of cohomology but are not equivalent in the derived category?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, homology-cohomology, derived-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category, the "complexes category", "homotopy category" and "derived category" denoted by $\mathcal{C(A)}$ , $\mathcal{K(A)}$ and $\mathcal{D(A)}$ respectively.

It is well known that

$$ f = g\ in\ \mathcal{C(A)} \Longrightarrow f = g\ in\ \mathcal{K(A)} \Longrightarrow f = g\ in\ \mathcal{D(A)} \Longrightarrow f\ and\ g\ induce\ the\ same\ morphisms\ of\ cohomology.$$

All three of these directions of implication are irreversible. It is easy to find counterexamples for the first two irreversible directions, but I have not found a counterexample for the irreversibility of the last direction.

So the question arises: Are there two morphisms $f$ and $g$ between complexes which induce the same morphisms of cohomology but are not equivalent in the "derived category" , i.e. , there is not an quasi-isomorphism $t$ such that $ft = gt$ or $tf = tg$ in "homotopy category" $\mathcal{K(A)}$?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is related with the existence of non-split extensions:

If $0 \to N \to E \to M \to 0$ is a non-split extension in $\mathcal{A}$, we obtain a non-zero map $f\colon M \to N[1]$ in $D(\mathcal{A})$. But clearly, $f$ is the zero map on cohomology.

Comment: If I understand the above construction correctly, a concrete example in the category of Abelian groups would be the chain map: $$\begin{array}[ccccccccc]
{}\to &0&\to&\mathbb{Z}&\stackrel{2}\to&\mathbb{Z}&\to&0&\to
\\
& \downarrow && \downarrow1&& \downarrow&& \downarrow
\\
\to &0&\to&\mathbb{Z}&\to&0&\to&0&\to
\end{array}
$$ Here we take $N=E=\mathbb{Z},\, M=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  It is easy to see that as claimed, this chain map is zero on cohomology but not zero in the homotopy category.  Is there an elementary way to see that it is not zero in the derived category?

Comment: I suppose it is easy to see that composing the above chain map with a quasi-isomorphism does not give a chain map homotopic to zero: e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670331/a-map-of-complexes-which-is-zero-on-cohomology-but-not-zero-in-d-mathcala

Comment: @tkf In this special case I would argue that the top row consists of projective objects and hence the Homs out of it in the derived category coincides with the Hom in the homotopy category. I was having in mind the isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_{D(\mathcal A)}(M, N[1]) \cong \mathrm{Ext}^1_{\mathcal A}(M,N)$.